# Apache mod_wsgi error: file not found (when the file exists)

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

So I'm just trying to display a simple page on my Apache server.

I have a wsgi file: /var/www/html/wsgi/myapp.wsgi

and my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>  

    WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/myapp /var/www/html/wsgi/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/wsgi>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```

this is the error.log (log level is info):

```
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.001384 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22390] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.001441 2015] [mpm_prefork:info] [pid 22390] AH00164: Server built: Jul 22 2014 14:36:38
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.001464 2015] [core:notice] [pid 22390] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.001976 2015] [:info] [pid 22505] mod_wsgi (pid=22505): Initializing Python.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.003966 2015] [:info] [pid 22504] mod_wsgi (pid=22504): Initializing Python.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.008001 2015] [:info] [pid 22502] mod_wsgi (pid=22502): Initializing Python.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.011764 2015] [:info] [pid 22503] mod_wsgi (pid=22503): Initializing Python.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.018442 2015] [:info] [pid 22501] mod_wsgi (pid=22501): Attach interpreter ''.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.029632 2015] [:info] [pid 22502] mod_wsgi (pid=22502): Attach interpreter ''.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.035609 2015] [:info] [pid 22505] mod_wsgi (pid=22505): Attach interpreter ''.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.038286 2015] [:info] [pid 22504] mod_wsgi (pid=22504): Attach interpreter ''.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:40.041199 2015] [:info] [pid 22503] mod_wsgi (pid=22503): Attach interpreter ''.
[Sun Feb 22 00:08:49.444674 2015] [core:info] [pid 22501] [client 10.0.0.58:57209] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/wsgi/myapp
```

I gather from [this site](http://terokarvinen.com/2012/hello-wsgi-python-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-apache2) that it's not actually a problem with the existence of the file but with the wsgi module but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/myapp /var/www/html/wsgi/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/wsgi/myapp>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are trying to access this app with wrong URL - the correct one is:

```
http://localhost/wsgi/myapp/wsgi
```

For remote host replace `localhost` with the domain name or IP address.

Or you haven't symlinked `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` with `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`. Don't forget to reload/restart apache after creating this symlink.

BTW. The lines with `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` in your configuration are not required as they point to the default log location.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    <Directory "/var/www/html/wsgi/">
        <Files myapp.wsgi>
            Allow from all
            Order deny,allow
        </Files>
     </Directory>
```

restart apache
         ...